# Form loaded using partial view, show the reponse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I am loading the content of a partial view using ajax and outputting the returned HTML directly to the page by populating the html of a div. Here's the ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
                    data: { productId: productId },
                    datatype: "text/plain",
                    type: "GET",
                    url: theUrl,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#contentArea").html(data);
                    }
                });
```

This all works as expected. Depending on a number of factors the actual html in the partial view varies, and one of the possible scenarios returns a form that asks for some feedback.

I have the client side validation working on this form but the server side validation is not cooperating.

My validation is FluentValidation and in my controller I have these couple of lines (myValidator is my FluentValidation validator and is working properly):

```
var valResult = myValidator.Validate(myRequest);
if (!valResult.IsValid) return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer);
```

This half works, the IsValid check fails whenever the data is invalid but then my redirect is simply reloading the page again without the server side validation messages in place. Presumably this is because I'm using a redirect.

How do I get it to reload the page but with the validation messages in place given that I'm dynamically loading this form using ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the validation errors back to your ViewModel and send that back to the view itself. I'm doing it like this:

```
var mailValidator = new Models.Dokumentacija.Validation.DokumentacijaMailValidation();
var mailValidatorResult = mailValidator.Validate(vm.MailPodatki);
if (!mailValidatorResult.IsValid)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    foreach (var error in mailValidatorResult.Errors) ModelState.AddModelError(string.Format("MailPodatki.{0}", error.PropertyName), error.ErrorMessage);
    return View(vm);
}
```

You should then return your ViewModel (now with error messages) so I think your Redirect won't work. Can you do a `return PartialView("_myPartial", vm);`?

Comment: I was able to work with the validation errors and change how I showed them so am marking this as the answer. Thanks.